# Detectron 2 ViTDet custom data set registration

Tags: python, object-detection, detectron

I'm currently exploring the ViTDet model in Detectron2 projects and I'm trying to run it on my custom dataset in COCO format. There is an [official instruction](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/datasets.html_) for using custom dataset but it seems to work on google colab or jupyter notebook but I'm running the evaluation inside the directory terminal (I'm not sure I clearly describe it).

What I did is inserting the code for loading and registering my custom dataset inside the config files and everytime I run the evaluation inside the terminal, it loads and registers my dataset again so it would take a long time when working with thousands of images (cuz u have to load images to get the size). Therefore, I'm wondering is there any way to register my custom data set only once and I can run the model after that?

my code in the config files:

```
def load_data_in_coco_format(cam_path, name):
    ...
    return images

def register_aic_data():
    ...
    # # 1. register a function which returns dicts
    # # TODO: make it general for `cams` currently for testing

    DatasetCatalog.register(name, lambda: load_data_in_coco_format(cam_path, name))

    # # 2. Optionally, add metadata about this dataset,
    # # since they might be useful in evaluation, visualization or logging
    MetadataCatalog.get(name).set(
        **metadata
    )

register_data()

dataloader = OmegaConf.create()
...
```

What I'm looking for is somewhat like the builtin dataset registration.

Many thanks